# jquery Resizeable malfunctioning in Firefox

Tags: jquery, resizable

in my web page i have a table and i want its first column to be resizeable. it works fine in IE8 but on Mozilla it shows resize icon in bottom right corner of the document. this is the code

```
$(".resizable").resizable({
            maxHeight: 25,
            maxWidth: 350,
            minHeight: 25,
            minWidth: 150
        });
```

here is how it shows up in IE8 [image]

here is how it shows up in Firefox [image]

plz see the resize icon on bottom right corner

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="resizable ui-resizable">Task Number<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; -moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on"></div></th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th style="width: 100px;">DeadLine</th>
            <th>Parent TaskID</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


             <tr class="1" id="row-0" style="">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 14px;" class="wrapper">

                          &nbsp;

                    </div>
                    TaskN

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="text" value="01/12/2010" style="text-align: center;" name="StartDate[0]" id="StartDate_0_" class="DatePicker 11 hasDatepicker"> 

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" value="7" name="Duration[0]" id="Duration_0_" class="DurationChange 11">

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>





             <tr class="2" id="row-1" style="">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 14px;" class="wrapper">

                          &nbsp;

                    </div>
                    TaskP

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="text" value="01/11/2010" style="text-align: center;" name="StartDate[1]" id="StartDate_1_" class="DatePicker 12 hasDatepicker"> 

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" value="7" name="Duration[1]" id="Duration_1_" class="DurationChange 12">

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>





             <tr class="3" id="row-2" style="color: blue;">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 14px;" class="wrapper">

                            <span lang="on" class="navigator">&nbsp;</span>


                    </div>
                    Task12

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                16/12/2010

                </td>
                <td>
                5

                </td>
                <td>18/11/2010</td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>





             <tr class="3.1" id="row-3" style="color: orange;">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 28px;" class="wrapper">

                            <span lang="on" class="navigator">&nbsp;</span>


                    </div>
                    Task2

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                10/12/2010

                </td>
                <td>
                5

                </td>
                <td>19/09/2010</td>
                <td>1</td>
             </tr>





             <tr class="3.1.1" id="row-4" style="color: red;">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 42px;" class="wrapper">

                            <span lang="on" class="navigator">&nbsp;</span>


                    </div>
                    Task3

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                22/12/2010

                </td>
                <td>
                1

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>2</td>
             </tr>





             <tr class="3.1.1.1" id="row-5" style="color: red;">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 56px;" class="wrapper">

                          &nbsp;

                    </div>
                    Task9

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="text" value="30/10/2010" style="text-align: center;" name="StartDate[5]" id="StartDate_5_" class="DatePicker 9 hasDatepicker"> 

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" value="34" name="Duration[5]" id="Duration_5_" class="DurationChange 9">

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>3</td>
             </tr>





             <tr class="3.1.2" id="row-6" style="color: orange;">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 42px;" class="wrapper">

                          &nbsp;

                    </div>
                    Task10

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="text" value="30/10/2010" style="text-align: center;" name="StartDate[6]" id="StartDate_6_" class="DatePicker 10 hasDatepicker"> 

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" value="12" name="Duration[6]" id="Duration_6_" class="DurationChange 10">

                </td>
                <td>04/10/2010</td>
                <td>2</td>
             </tr>





             <tr class="3.2" id="row-7" style="color: red;">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 28px;" class="wrapper">

                          &nbsp;

                    </div>
                    task5

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="text" value="25/10/2010" style="text-align: center;" name="StartDate[7]" id="StartDate_7_" class="DatePicker 5 hasDatepicker"> 

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" value="3" name="Duration[7]" id="Duration_7_" class="DurationChange 5">

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
             </tr>





             <tr class="3.3" id="row-8" style="color: orange;">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 28px;" class="wrapper">

                          &nbsp;

                    </div>
                    001

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="text" value="19/10/2010" style="text-align: center;" name="StartDate[8]" id="StartDate_8_" class="DatePicker 7 hasDatepicker"> 

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" value="5" name="Duration[8]" id="Duration_8_" class="DurationChange 7">

                </td>
                <td>23/10/2010</td>
                <td>1</td>
             </tr>





             <tr class="4" id="row-9" style="">
                <td width="150">
                    <div style="width: 14px;" class="wrapper">

                          &nbsp;

                    </div>
                    Task4

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                15/01/2011

                </td>
                <td>
                5

                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>




    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: this is doctype tag !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"

Comment: There are a **large** number of validation errors with that markup with XHTML 1.0 Strict. If this is a general web app, I'd strongly recommend HTML over XHTML. If you really need to use XHTML for some reason, be sure you understand the issues: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq It requires special server configuration (otherwise it's going to be treated as tag soup) and if you need to support IE, you need to use a hack.

Comment: I have similar problem today, 2014, only at Firefox: this jsfiddle works fine with Chrome or Opera but not with Firefox, http://jsfiddle.net/PHbHN/29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem by putting the div in td and assigning resizable class to td instead of td itself. its now working fine both in IE and firefox

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your table markup is invalid, but in a way that IE is willing to let you get away with. Firefox is more strict about table markup. <s>If you'll show us the full markup, we'll be able to help you better. (And of course, I may well be wrong.)</s>

**Update** You haven't mentioned your DOCTYPE, but the markup is invalid in HTML5 according to the [W3C Validator Service](http://validator.w3.org/). There are several issues, but the most relevant is that `th` cannot contain a `div`. Most browsers will relocate those things outside the table when they run into them. The validator says it's valid HTML4 barring some niggles with attributes, though, so...

**Edit** Made this a community wiki because it doesn't have an answer (yet) and I have to move on to doing other things. Good luck with it.

Comment: how do i make my td's resizeable

Comment: Downvoted. The tips are ok, but the information here is too generic and even with correct and validating markup this won't work in Firefox due to a firefox bug. See my answer in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammed's answer works, put a div inside the th and make that resizable.

This issue is known to the jQuery team:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8120

They can't really fix it because it's actually an open issue in Firefox itself:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895

Answer (score -1):

I have fiexd resizable for  Mozilla.

jsfiddle.net/tanawat/FVr5g/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.